# How to Add text in a video

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a video that lasts a duration of 5 minutes now I want to add text in that video for a particular time of say 5 - 15 seconds.

Can any one help me out. I have tried below code for adding text to an image

```
CATextLayer *subtitle1Text = [[CATextLayer alloc] init];
[subtitle1Text setFont:@"Helvetica-Bold"];
[subtitle1Text setFontSize:36];
[subtitle1Text setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, 100)];
[subtitle1Text setString:_subTitle1.text];
[subtitle1Text setAlignmentMode:kCAAlignmentCenter];
[subtitle1Text setForegroundColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];

// 2 - The usual overlay
CALayer *overlayLayer = [CALayer layer];
[overlayLayer addSublayer:subtitle1Text];
overlayLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
[overlayLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];


CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];
CALayer *videoLayer = [CALayer layer];
parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
[parentLayer addSublayer:videoLayer];
[parentLayer addSublayer:overlayLayer];

composition.animationTool = [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool 
                             videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:videoLayer inLayer:parentLayer];
```

Can one one help me how to do it for videos

Comment: you can't add text in video

Comment: @user3446178 have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try the below method to edit a video frame by frame using `AVFoundation.framework`,

```
-(void)startEditingVideoAtURL:(NSURL *)resourceURL
{
    NSError * error = nil;


    // Temp File path to write the edited movie
    NSURL * movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), resourceURL.lastPathComponent]];

    NSFileManager * fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

     NSError * error;

     BOOL success = [fm removeItemAtPath:movieURL.path error:&error];


    // Create AVAssetWriter to convert the images into movie
    AVAssetWriter * videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:movieURL fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie error:&error];

    NSParameterAssert(videoWriter);

    AVAsset * avAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:resourceURL options:nil];


    // Set your out put video frame here
    NSDictionary * videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:480.0], AVVideoWidthKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:480.0], AVVideoHeightKey,
                                    nil];


    // Create AVAssetWriterInput with video Settings
    AVAssetWriterInput* videoWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput
                                            assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                            outputSettings:videoSettings];

    NSDictionary * sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA], kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey,
                                                            [NSNumber numberWithInt:480.0], kCVPixelBufferWidthKey,
                                                            [NSNumber numberWithInt:480.0], kCVPixelBufferHeightKey,
                                                            nil];

    AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor * assetWriterPixelBufferAdaptor1 = [[AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor alloc] initWithAssetWriterInput:videoWriterInput sourcePixelBufferAttributes:sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary];

    NSParameterAssert(videoWriterInput);

    NSParameterAssert([videoWriter canAddInput:videoWriterInput]);

    videoWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;

    [videoWriter addInput:videoWriterInput];

    NSError *aerror = nil;

    // Create AVAssetReader to read the video files frame by frame
    AVAssetReader * reader = [[AVAssetReader alloc] initWithAsset:avAsset error:&aerror];

    NSArray * vTracks = [avAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    AVAssetReaderTrackOutput * asset_reader_output = nil;

    if (vTracks.count)
    {
        AVAssetTrack * videoTrack = [vTracks objectAtIndex:0];

        videoWriterInput.transform = videoTrack.preferredTransform;

        NSDictionary *videoOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA] forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];

        asset_reader_output = [[AVAssetReaderTrackOutput alloc] initWithTrack:videoTrack outputSettings:videoOptions];

        [reader addOutput:asset_reader_output];
    }
    else
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:EDITOR_FAILED_NOTI object:resourceURL.path];

        [reader cancelReading];

        queueInProgress = NO;

        [self removeCurrentVideo];

        return;
    }

    //audio setup

    AVAssetWriterInput * audioWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput
                                             assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio
                                             outputSettings:nil];

    AVAssetReader * audioReader = [AVAssetReader assetReaderWithAsset:avAsset error:&error];

    NSArray * aTrack = [avAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];

    AVAssetReaderOutput * readerOutput = nil;

    if (aTrack.count)
    {
        AVAssetTrack * audioTrack = [aTrack objectAtIndex:0];

        readerOutput = [AVAssetReaderTrackOutput assetReaderTrackOutputWithTrack:audioTrack outputSettings:nil];

        [audioReader addOutput:readerOutput];
    }

    NSParameterAssert(audioWriterInput);

    NSParameterAssert([videoWriter canAddInput:audioWriterInput]);

    audioWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = NO;

    [videoWriter addInput:audioWriterInput];

    [videoWriter startWriting];

    [videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];

    [reader startReading]; // Here the video reader starts the reading

    dispatch_queue_t _processingQueue = dispatch_queue_create("assetAudioWriterQueue", NULL);

    [videoWriterInput requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:_processingQueue usingBlock:
     ^{
         while ([videoWriterInput isReadyForMoreMediaData])
         {
             CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer;

             if ([reader status] == AVAssetReaderStatusReading &&
                 (sampleBuffer = [asset_reader_output copyNextSampleBuffer]))
             {
                 CMTime currentTime = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer);

                 CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

                 CIImage * _ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:imageBuffer];

                 CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

                 size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);

                 size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);

                 size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);

                 void * baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);

                 size_t bufferSize = CVPixelBufferGetDataSize(imageBuffer);

                 CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, baseAddress, bufferSize, NULL);

                 CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

                 CGDataProviderRelease(dataProvider);

                 // Add your text drawing code here

                 CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);

                 CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorSpace);

                 BOOL result = [assetWriterPixelBufferAdaptor1 appendPixelBuffer:imageBuffer withPresentationTime:currentTime];

                 CVPixelBufferRelease(imageBuffer);

                 CFRelease(sampleBuffer);

                 if (!result)
                 {
                     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                                    {
                                        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:EDITOR_FAILED_NOTI object:resourceURL.path];

                                        [reader cancelReading];

                                        queueInProgress = NO;

                                        [self removeCurrentVideo];
                                    });

                     break;
                 }
             }
             else
             {
                 [videoWriterInput markAsFinished]; // This will called, once video write done

                 switch ([reader status])
                 {
                     case AVAssetReaderStatusReading:
                         // the reader has more for other tracks, even if this one is done
                         break;

                     case AVAssetReaderStatusCompleted:
                     {
                         if (!readerOutput)
                         {
                             if ([videoWriter respondsToSelector:@selector(finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:)])
                                 [videoWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:^
                                  {
                                      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                                                     {

                                                     });
                                  }];
                             else
                             {
                                 if ([videoWriter finishWriting])
                                 {
                                     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                                                    {


                                                    });
                                 }
                             }

                             break;

                         }

                         [audioReader startReading];

                         [videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];

                         dispatch_queue_t mediaInputQueue = dispatch_queue_create("mediaInputQueue", NULL);

                         [audioWriterInput requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:mediaInputQueue usingBlock:^
                          {
                              while (audioWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData) {
                                  CMSampleBufferRef nextBuffer;
                                  if ([audioReader status] == AVAssetReaderStatusReading &&
                                      (nextBuffer = [readerOutput copyNextSampleBuffer]))
                                  {
                                      if (nextBuffer)
                                      {
                                          [audioWriterInput appendSampleBuffer:nextBuffer];
                                      }

                                      CFRelease(nextBuffer);

                                  }else
                                  {
                                      [audioWriterInput markAsFinished];

                                      switch ([audioReader status])
                                      {
                                          case AVAssetReaderStatusCompleted:

                                              if ([videoWriter respondsToSelector:@selector(finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:)])
                                                  [videoWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:^
                                                   {

                                                   }];
                                              else
                                              {
                                                  if ([videoWriter finishWriting])
                                                  {

                                                  }
                                              }

                                              break;
                                      }
                                  }
                              }

                          }
                          ];
                         break;
                     }
                         // your method for when the conversion is done
                         // should call finishWriting on the writer
                         //hook up audio track

                     case AVAssetReaderStatusFailed:
                     {

                         break;
                     }
                 }

                 break;
             }
         }
     }
     ];

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide comments in your code please, as I'm not even sure fully what's going on in it after reading it. Think this requires an explanation.